# The "isanswered" search option isn't working as described

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

From the [official help page on searching](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

> The following search operators can be used with values of yes/no, true/false, or 1/0 (each pair behaves the same):

> - [...]
> - `isanswered:` yes/true/1 returns only questions that have at least [one accepted or positively-scored answer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/); no/false/0 returns only questions with no accepted or positively-scored answers.

### But this is not how `isanswered:` is actually working!

For example, see [this query](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3A0+answers%3A1). Searching on the SFF site using `is:question isanswered:0 answers:1` should return questions that have at least one answer but no accepted or positively-scored answers. Instead, the results include questions like [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68104/how-are-years-measured-in-doctor-who) and [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22624/world-with-words-of-power) which **have accepted answers**.

---

The description of the `isanswered:` search option should instead read something like:

> - `isanswered:` yes/true/1 returns only questions that have at least one positively-scored answer; no/false/0 returns only questions with no positively-scored answers.

Well, either that or the actual search algorithm should be changed, but I bet I know which is easier!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say the documentation was incorrect here - given that we do have a `hasaccepted` operator that does take accepted status into account.

So, fixed the documentation here.