# isanswered:0 in searches returns both questions and answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Speaking of [The "isanswered" search option isn't working as described](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277598/302251), copying the relevant part from an [old bug report of mine on Ask Ubuntu Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13860/380067);

From [How do I search? - Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

> - `isanswered`: yes/true/1 returns only questions that have at least one positively-scored answer; **no/false/0 returns only questions with no positively-scored answers**.

But `isanswered:0` [returns both questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=isanswered%3A0+meta).

When I'm searching using `isanswered:0`, according to the description, I'd expect to see only *questions* in the results, not *answers*.

While I agree that since answers can't have answers answers technically fit the criterion, perhaps it would be more reasonable if `isanswered:0` returned only questions.

Comment: [Can confirm](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=isanswered%3A0+is%3Aanswer). Bit of an *oops* for Oded, I imagine :-/

Comment: You can use `answers:0` or `isaccepted:0` instead

Comment: Looks like a bug - `isanswered` should imply `is:question`, which it doesn't seem to be doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. `isanswered` will now imply `is:question` when included!

Thanks for the report.